# Trace of packet

Tags: windows, networking

I have one question about IP packet trace: is it possible to watch an IP-packet trace in my Windows 7 system? I recieve IP-packets and I want to know - where do this data move: which DLLs do they use, which functions do they call and etc.

Thanks.

Comment: TCPView http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437

Comment: Netmon (latest version) will show application associated with packets

Answer (score 0):

Well the most likely solution would be a packetsniffer tool of some kind.

Simply a packet sniffer captures all of the packets of data that pass through a network. Typically, the packet sniffer would only capture packets that were intended for the machine in question. However, if placed different modes, the packet sniffer is also capable of capturing ALL packets travelling over the network regardless of destination.

Hope this helps

Dan

http://www.visualiptrace.com